# After upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, MOTD always says 0 new packages can be updated

Tags: apt, ubuntu-14.04, package-management, upgrade

I'm not a server expert and so I'm experiencing some upgrade issues with Ubuntu. A little history: my Digital Ocean droplet was running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, then a few months ago I upgraded to a newer HWE to continue to receive security updates for the 12.04. Recently I upgraded Ubuntu to the 14.04 LTS. Everything seems to be working fine except I'm not receiving any notifications that there are packages to be updated. Upon logging into my server the Message of the Day continues to display:

```
0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.
```

which just can't be right for 3 weeks now...?

running `sudo apt-get update` runs without error and `sudo apt-get upgrade` says `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

I have a feeling that my `/etc/apt/sources.list` was corrupted somehow after upgrading to the new HWE kernal and then the new LTS. Below are the sources listed currently. Does anyone see any issues with this list? any advice would be appreciated.

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list

#

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04.3 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20130820.2)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
## DigitalOcean mirrors for blazing speed!
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
## DigitalOcean mirrors for blazing speed!
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
## DigitalOcean mirrors for blazing speed!
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
## DigitalOcean mirrors for blazing speed!
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
## DigitalOcean mirrors for blazing speed!
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## DigitalOcean mirrors for blazing speed!
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse
# deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
# deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
# deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Comment: What do you expect instead?

Comment: I think I'd have an update by now.. maybe not.. but after a few weeks and 0 updates it just seems too long, no?

Comment: Yeah maybe...maybe not. Who knows? Maybe you could actually [check](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/trusty/) and compare versions of packages which are installed on your machine with the available ones. Get your facts straight, so there is anything to work with.. By the way: "Maybe" (again: nobody knows) automatic updates are enabled on your machine.

Comment: My LTS systems haven't seen any updates in a few weeks either. This is normal. Don't worry.  On the remote chance that DigitalOcean's mirrors are outdated or out of sync, just use the official `us.archive.ubuntu.com` mirrors.

Comment: Thanks Will, it's good to know I'm not the only one not seeing any updates lately. The timing of my upgrade over the holidays may have been the coincidence here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu LTS versions don't get many updates. In fact, the only updates you see in a LTS version are

1. security updates
2. bugfixes for major bugs (file loss bugs etc)

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates#When for when exactly an LTS version gets updates.

Comment: Thanks Dominik. I think I've just been used to my older 12.04 server having what seemed like updates everyday. I'll just be satisfied all is good now ;-) Also appreciate the link, I'll keep tabs on that if I continue to see no changes.